# Inverse Mellin Transform of $f(w)=\exp\big(\frac{1}{\log w}\big)?$

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, complex-integration, integral-transforms, mellin-transform

This question is motivated by the sequence of functions generated by inverse Mellin transforms:

$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(z-1) \to \frac{2K_1(2\sqrt{z})}{\sqrt{z}}\to e^{\frac{1}{\log z}} \to~ ?$$

Once the last function is found the length of the sequence will be $4$ because there are $4$ total functions.

> To complete the sequence what is the inverse Mellin Transform of $f(w)=\exp\big(\frac{1}{\log w}\big)?$

We can set this up as:

$$  f(p)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{f(w)}{p^w}~dw  $$

Neither Wolfram Alpha nor Mathematica can calculate it.

I suspect $f(p)$ is some kind of step function.

Comment: Your question is hard to interpret as you've defined a relationship between two variables, and the inverse Mellin transform applies to a function F(s) of a single variable.

Comment: @StevenClark Now is it hard to interpret?

Comment: The question now makes sense but please remove everything before "brings me to my question:" which is not quite meaningful nor useful.

Comment: Yes that clarifies the question, thanks.

Comment: @reuns I'm just putting context - you can't just state the question and that's it

Comment: The inverse Mellin transform $\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{2 K_1\left(2 \sqrt{s}\right)}{\sqrt{s}}\right](w)=e^{\frac{1}{\log (w)}}$ is only valid for $0<w<1$. In other words, $\int\limits_0^1 e^{\frac{1}{\log (w)}}\, w^{s-1} \, dw=\frac{2 K_1\left(2 \sqrt{s}\right)}{\sqrt{s}}$, so $\frac{2 K_1\left(2 \sqrt{s}\right)}{\sqrt{s}}$ isn't really the Mellin transform of $e^{\frac{1}{\log (w)}}$, rather it's the Mellin transform of $e^{\frac{1}{\log (w)}}(1-\theta(w-1)$.

Comment: @StevenClark okay

Comment: @StevenClark but $\frac{2 K_1\left(2 \sqrt{s}\right)}{\sqrt{s}}$ *is* the Mellin Transform (on bounded support) of $e^{\frac{1}{\log (w)}}$ for $s>0$ and $0<w<1$

Comment: I could have written $e^{\frac{1}{\log(w)}}(1-\theta(w-1)$ more simply as $e^{\frac{1}{\log(w)}}\, \theta(1-w)$. Since $\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{2 K_1\left(2 \sqrt{s}\right)}{\sqrt{s}}\right](w)=e^{\frac{1}{\log (w)}}$ is only valid for $0<w<1$, I don't see how the inverse Mellin transform of $e^{\frac{1}{\log (w)}}$ is related to the first three functions since the inverse Mellin transform is evaluated along an imaginary line.

Comment: Assuming $e^{\frac{1}{\log (w)}}$ is actually valid for $0<\Re(w)<1$, if you want to make it's inverse Mellin Transform a valid continuation of the first three functions, it seems to me you'd have to select $c$ such that $0<c<1$, but $e^{\frac{1}{\log(w)}}$ has a pole at $w=1$, so I believe the inverse Mellin transform actually needs to be evaluated for $c>1$.

Comment: @StevenClark why can't you have $0<c<1$ for the inverse Mellin Transform? Can Mathematica evaluate something like $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{1/2}^{1/2+i}\frac{f(w)}{p^w}~dw$?

Comment: If $f(w)$ is analytic in the strip $0<\Re(w)<1$, then for $0<c<1$ the inverse Mellin transform $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{c-i\, \infty}^{c+i\, \infty}\frac{f(w)}{p^w}~dw$  is only valid when $f(c+i\, t)$ tends to zero uniformly as $t\to\pm\infty$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_inversion_theorem#Method). The problem is that $\underset{t\to\pm\infty }{\text{lim}}e^{\frac{1}{\log (c+i\, t)}}=1$ which seems to imply $e^{\frac{1}{\log(w)}}$ doesn't have an inverse Mellin transform.

Comment: I don't believe the inverse Mellin transform integral $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{c-i\, \infty}^{c+i\, \infty}\frac{e^{\frac{1}{\log(w)}}}{p^w}\,dw$ converges in a normal sense, but perhaps it converges in a distributional sense. For example, $\mathcal{M}_x[\delta (x-1)](s)=1$ which implies $\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}[1](x)=\delta(x-1)$.